# Como obter a quantidade de registros de um DataReader?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, vb.net, ado.net

Estou fazendo uma consulta em um banco de dados, porém preciso saber quantos registros eu vou obter dessa consulta, antes mesmo de começar a malha.

> Obs: Não quero colocar um contador dentro da malha, preciso do valor
>   antes*

```
cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, conexao)
myDR = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
while myDR.read 
...
end while
```

Comment: A resposta lhe resolveu o que queria? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

A única forma é pedir para o SQL contar para você, algo assim:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tabela WHERE alguma condição aqui
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ADO.NET/Count.cs).

Isso pode não ser o ideal por gerar 2 consultas ao banco e deve ser evitado se tiver alguma outra forma.

Comment: Entendi, eu conheço esse método, porém queria algo mais eficaz.

Comment: será que um `select @@ROWCOUNT` logo após ele abrir o `DataReader` não daria também.

Comment: @PabloVargas Dependendo do que deseja, pode.

Comment: @FelipeWalleg eficaz é, só não é o mais eficiente. Mas fora alguma solução muito específica e que provavelmente não é o ideal também, é o único jeito. O que eu faria é tentar não precisar dessa informação nesse momento. Em geral ela é desnecessária na situação descrita.

Comment: Verdade, porém eu preciso dela pois quando chegar no ultimo registro do read, eu preciso adicionar uns valores, mas tem que ser no ultimo registro, queria aproveitar esse loop para fazer, pois estou escrevendo um relatório, e seria no final de cada dia.

Comment: Alguma coisa me diz que está fazendo alguma coisa errada. Mas não tenho como opinar sem ver.

Answer (score 1):

Bem, eu usei o SQL Server e fiz as consultas abaixo, para evitar dois processamentos no banco - um para teste e outro para os dados - considere os exemplos abaixo que eu testei e veja se lhe ajuda ou é o que busca:

Criei uma tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE #dados 
( 
     nome VARCHAR(20) 
);
```

Depois eu inserir alguns dados nela:

```
INSERT INTO #dados (nome) 
SELECT 'A' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'B' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'C'
```

**Opção 1:**

```
SELECT nome, Count(*) OVER (partition BY 1) AS QtdRegistros 
  FROM #dados
```

**Opção 2:**

```
SELECT a.*, b.QtdRegistros
  FROM #dados a 
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT Count(*) AS QtdRegistros 
                     FROM #dados) b
```

Depois liberei a memória:

```
DROP TABLE #dados
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Alterando o comportamento de execução do seu comando, você pode obter o total de linhas que sua consulta executou, através da propriedade `RecordsAffected`.

Veja abaixo:

```
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection | CommandBehavior.SingleResult))
{
    var totalDeLinhas = reader.RecordsAffected;
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //TODO: sua implementação aqui
    }
}
```